# How to terminate ssh in while loop via terminal?

Tags: powershell

I have a while loop in my powershell script that is constantly refreshing some information it gets from a external server.

Similar to this:

```
while (1) {
    $queue = ssh ...
    Clear-Host
    Write-Output $queue
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

While that works, I'm unable to break the execution from the terminal.
Normally a script can be stopped by pressing "STRG + C" but with this code the console just isn't reacting to "STRG + C" and is continuing the execution.

I'm also unable to enter `Enter` + `~` + `.` to terminate the ssh command as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29942/how-can-i-break-out-of-ssh-when-it-locks

How can I make this code break able?

Comment: I tried this in the PS console, ISE and VSCode and was able to break out with `CTRL+C` in each.

Comment: @boxdog I changed my post. It seems related to the actual `ssh` call I'm doing there. I didn't test it with the `Get-Date` I just used as example in the question. I'm not sure how to make a test able code snipped with `ssh`.

Comment: Why aren't you using `psremoting` over `ssh`?  PowerShell Core and the WinRM protocol (although I think it uses ssh under the covers) are supported on Linux.  As a side-note, you can break into the debugger using `CTRL+BREAK` to terminate the loop, but this is assuming your console isn't hung by the `ssh` call.